# Is Joomla showon only for backend?

Tags: xml, plugins, joomla, user-profile

I'm changing user profile plugin in Joomla 3.3, using method described in 
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/user-profile
tutorial.
Everything works and OK.

But I want to make some changes in profile.
In this profile plugin there are  two xml files, 
One for administrator controlling what will appear in registration and profile editing forms, and the second one for the registration (profile editing) form itself.

**showon feature works good in the first xml file, but does nothing in second file.**

Any ideas about reason and solution ?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).

Comment: Is there any reason for deleting it from stckoverflow before posting it in joomla.stackexchange.com ?